# jquery slider that doesn't activate via a button?

Tags: jquery, slider

I am trying to find a jquery slidedown effect, I want the name of my website to slide in from the left or right when the page is opened. I don't want there to be a button that you click to activate it, just make it slide automatically when the page is opened :)
All help is appreciated!

Comment: You want the [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method

Comment: add plugin in document ready?

Answer (score 0):

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/fQmnu/3/) animating the width of your logo.

Try something like this code:

```
$(function() {
  $('#logo').animate({
    width: 500,
  }, 1000);
});
```

Now in your html give you website name (image?) a id of `logo`.

In your css set its styling to:

```
#logo {
  width:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Remember to include jQuery if you are going to try my code. You can see this on line 1 of my example:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: how do I link the jquery library thing? Sorry, I am just new to html and that stuff!

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way I can have text do that instead of an image?

Comment: @Optional There is yes, ill update my answer in a few minutes